# Team Project deletion stuck in "Deleted (Processing)"

Tags: tfs, team-project

My Team Project stuck in status "Deleted (Processing)" for 2 days. I deleted it by using the TFS Admin Console and after that it stuck in the status mentioned above. No log and no eventlog was generated so i can't see any problems. Trying to delete it again via the UI didn't work. I restarted the TFS 2010 server yesterday but this didn't help even. How can i delete it now?

Comment: There are a number of jobs that do he actual cleanup/deletion, they run in the background. If your Team project was exceptionally big (or had lots of builds/test results/sources), it could take a while for the deletes to process. You could try executing `prc_DeleteUnusedContent` to force a cleanup run. http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19932.reduce-the-size-of-tfs-databases-after-cleaning-some-source-control-files.aspx

Comment: I will take a look on Monday. But for information, the team project was empty. I created it 4 hours before I deleted it.

Comment: Does this issue happen on each team project in a particular team project collection? How about another team project collection? Any information under the Logs section in the console

Answer (score 0):

You can try [TFSDeleteProject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/tfs/administer/command-line/tfsdeleteproject-cmd) command to delete team projects:

```
TFSDeleteproject [/q] [/force] [/excludewss] /collection:URL TeamProjectName
```